# How to remove white gap between container and the edge of viewport?

Tags: css

i am stuck with one problem and the biggest problem is that i cant even imagine what is it and how to solve that problem . 
Here is the image from my browser window

[image]

> As you can see , there is a white gap when making window smaller. The black block on the top of the page is given position fixed and width 100% . My breakpoints are ` [1200, 900 , 600]

Here is the link of website in Github pages ` [Education website](https://norayr-bp.github.io/education/#)

Would be glad to to be given some help .

Comment: please, at least provide your `CSS` code.

Comment: Sorry i can't . In order to see it you just can follow the link i provided .

Comment: have you tried overflow-x: hidden;?

Comment: Yes , it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mail input in the footer is to big for small devices and overflows the page.

You can fix this by setting the width of the input to 100% and putting a line breake between the input and the button. Or you can add `flex-direction: column;` to `.main-footer__form` for screen widths smaller 700px.

But probably the best way would be to remove `position: absolute;` from the `.main-footer__form` and set the `rowspan` of the cell to 3. You should combine this with `flex-direction: column;` for screens smaller 600px.

```css
.main-footer__form {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-footer__form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="main-footer__table">
  <!-- ... -->
  <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <form action="#" class="main-footer__form">
      <input type="email" name="mail">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="→">
    </form>
  </td>
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```